# Why celery-haystack?

Tags: django, django-haystack, django-celery

For a django project i like to run index updated by a celery worker to not hit the page parse time. I noticed celery-haystack that is able to do this but i'm wondering why it's that complicated. A much simpler solution would be to simply apply an async task from a post_save signal and invoke the signal processor from there, so not to apply the async part from within the signal processor but before.

I guess i'm missing something?

I'm aware that instances may not exist any more in case of delete signals...

Comment: Any insight you gained after thinking about this? What did you end up using?

Answer (score 0):

So celery is only the task distributor, right? And indexing is jobs to be done. Search is the end result. When your resource is limited, tasks will be queued up and scheduled to be ran workers are available. You can pursue your approach just fine, but Celery will optimize by delegating tasks to different workers, which may reside in other machines.

Answer (score 0):

I kind of forgot about the details.... (sorry). But to comment: i ended up not using celery-haystack but instead use django signals (not just post_save but i created more specific custom signals) that trigger async celery tasks (so delegate to other queue's/nodes) and these run the index update using the signal processor. I also extended the signal processor to support update and removal of single objects and iterable of objects.
Paul